# Manage jsf1.2 component id as my own component id

Tags: jsf, datatable, onchange

I am new on jsf1.2 .and I want to manage a component id in my option.

**Q:** In dataTable, same type component in different rows have a same component id,so when I want do some `onchangeAction` (e.g refresh value) by a4j, it will refresh the whole component, which is not right. I want to manage the component id by myself.

> ID: qCol_value_CSLB
>   CLIENTID:
>   detailTagForm:query_newentry:id__21e17a4:_21e17a4:data1:0:qCol_value_CSLB
>   detailTagForm:query_newentry:id__21e17a4:_21e17a4:data1:1:qCol_value_CSLB
>   detailTagForm:query_newentry:id__21e17a4:_21e17a4:data1:2:qCol_value_CSLB

same id but different row in dataTable.